# How to import class from another file

Tags: python

I am developing a bmi calculator. I have a main program and a user defined class in another file so basically 2 py files. The main program imports the user defined class. The main program is bmi_main and user defined is bmi_userdefined. The class in userdefined is Bmi_calculator. How do I import class from userdefined file to main file. I’m using pycharm.

Please advise. Both files are in same folder and same directory path

Comment: `from bmi_userdefined import Bmi_calculator`?

Comment: `from .bmi_userdefined import Bmi_calculator` at the to of the bmi_main.py file

Comment: On `bmi_mai`n module, just called from `bmi_userdefined` import `Bmi_calculator`

Answer (score 1):

in your `bmi_userdefined.py`:

```
class Bmi_calculator():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
        # your codes
```

then in your `bmi_main.py`:

```
from bmi_userdefined import Bmi_calculator

Bmi_calculator.__init__ # or whatever function or variable you wanna use
```

Comment: Why __init__? My class has different functions apart from init like str, private and public methods.

Comment: @Deepika it's just an example, replace it with your code !

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead like this:

```
from <file that has the class in> import <the class name you want to import>
```

For instance:

```
from file_A import Class_A
```

Comment: Ok I will try this. My main function will run like this if __name__ == '__main__': should I write the import statement before this right at the top of the main program

Comment: All the imports should be done at the top of your code.